# Bibtex removes dot in journal name after processing

Tags: bibtex, natbib, arxiv, google-scholar

I am using a bib file that contains numerous articles from arXiv. The citation format for the same looks like this (content of test.bib; the bibtex item is obtained from Google Scholar):

```
@article{auth2020title,
    title={Title of the paper},
    author={Auth, A and Auth, B and Auth, C},
    journal={arXiv preprint arXiv:1234.45678},
    year={2020}
}
```

While I compile the manuscript file, it results in a reference that does not contain the dot (".") for the arXiv journal name. See below.
Content of test.tex:

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{spbasic}

\begin{document}
This is just a filler \citep{auth2020title}.

\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you should show a complete example, that make it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: I added the example. Is it okay? @UlrikeFischer

Comment: hm, the bib-style quite explicitly remove all dots in the journal name.  you probably will to either adapt the bst and remove this `remove.dots` function, or you should use a command like \period in the bib (and then define this as \newcommand\period{.}).

Comment: Is this the appropriate `.bib` entry type for this? I should think it would be the same as for other online entries, and not `article`, in which case no dot removal is likely to happen. The problem arises because you're putting something that is not a journal name into the journal field. You've added the tag `google-scholar` which doesn't seem relevant. Perhaps this is the entry you got from that source? Online `bibtex` entries are notoriously bad.

Comment: See e.g. [Software-generated bibliographic entries: common errors and other mistakes to check before use](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053)

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes, Google Scholar generates this bibtex entry for arXiv article.